# Edit circle created on initialisation

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have created a circle using the code below, however it is not editable.

```
var test = L.circle([50.5, 30.5], {radius: 200}).addTo(map);
```

How do I make it editable when I click on the edit icon in the toolbar?

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable provides many editable polygons

Comment: If you're using Leaflet.draw for this (as the question's tags suggest), show us the relevant code about that. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as well.